# Which supervised machine learning classification method suits for randomly spread classes?

Tags: machine-learning, multilabel-classification, supervised-learning

If classes are randomly spread or it is having more noise, which type of supervised ML classification model will give better results, and why?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro & **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to say which classifier will perform best on general problems. It often requires testing of a variety of algorithms on a given problem in order to determine which classifier performs best.

Best performance is also dependent on the nature of the problem. There is a great answer in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44172162/f1-score-vs-roc-auc) which looks at various scoring metrics. For each problem, one needs to understand and consider which scoring metric will be best.

All of that said, neural networks, Random Forest classifiers, Support Vector Machines, and a variety of others are all candidates for creating useful models given that classes are, as you indicated, equally distributed. When classes are [imbalanced](https://machinelearningmastery.com/what-is-imbalanced-classification/), the rules shift slightly, as most ML algorithms assume balance.

My suggestion would be to try a few different algorithms, and tune the hyper parameters, to compare them for your specific application. You will often find one algorithm is better, but not remarkably so. In my experience, often of far greater importance, is how your data are preprocessed and how your features are prepared. Once again this is a highly generic answer as it depends greatly on your given application.