# SMOTE Algorithm and Classification: overrated prediction success

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation, oversampling

I'm facing a problem about which I can't find any answer. I have a binary classification problem (output Y=0 or Y=1) with Y=1 the minority class (actually Y=1 indicates default of a company, with proportion=0.02 in the original dataframe).
Therefore, I computed oversampling using SMOTE algorithm on my training set only (after splitting my dataframe in training and testing sets). I train a logistic regression on my training set (with proportions of class "defaut"=0.3) and then look at the ROC Curve and MSE to test whether my algorithm predicts well the default.
I get very good results in terms both of AUC (AUC=0.89) and MSE (MSE=0.06).
However, when I then try to look more preciselly and individually at my predictions, I find that 20% of default aren't well predicted.
Do you have a method to evaluate well the quality of my prediction (quality means for me predictions that predict well default). I thought that AUC was a good criterium... 
So far do you also have a method in order to improve my regression? 
Thanks

Comment: MSE is meaningless in classification settings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every classification problem you can build a **[confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix)**.

This is a two way entry matrix, and lets you see not only the *true positives/true negatives* (**TP/TN**), which are your correct predictions, but **also** the false positives (**FP**)/false negatives (**FN**), and this is most of the time your true interest.

FP and FN are the errors that your model make, you can track how well your model is doing in detecting either the TP (1-FP) or the TN (1-FN), by using **sensitivity** or **specificity** ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity)).

Note that you can't improve one without lowering the other. So sometimes you need to pick one.

A good compromise is the [F1-score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score), which tries to average the two.

So if you're more interested in *defaults* (lets imagine that `defaults=Positive Class`), you'll prefer a model with a higher **sensitivity**. But remember to not neglect completely the specificity either.

Here an example code in R:

```
# to get the confusion matrix and some metrics
caret::confusionMatrix(iris$Species, sample(iris$Species))
```

Comment: Ok thanks I'll have a look at this! However the notions of sensitivity and specificity also count in AUC which is in my example very good. What's then the difference between looking at AUC and looking at confusion matrix? My question might be stupid I'm sorry but I do not really see the difference

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/210700/how-to-choose-between-roc-auc-and-f1-score this may help you a little. I forgot to mention that AUC is a good average, sometimes just like f1-score

Comment: other good answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44172162/f1-score-vs-roc-auc and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698161/how-to-interpret-almost-perfect-accuracy-and-auc-roc-but-zero-f1-score-precisio#34698935

Comment: I recommend looking at the precision recall curve. Recall is the same as sensitivity but precision is how many of the positives that get predicted are actually true ie: TP/(TP+FP). On the other hand specificity which is used in AUC will get higher for all the true negatives that you predict. If you have imbalanced data that is mostly negative then true negatives are easy to predict and will inflate AUC. https://www.kaggle.com/general/7517